# Обновление документа через js

Tags: javascript

Допустим, есть документ который при открытии получает определённые значения. Они всегда разные. Далее, во втором документе нужно получать всё новые и новые данные.
Сделал так:

```
setInterval(function() { $("#document1").load("document.php"); }, 1000);
```

Ну, соответственно "document1" и есть id того, куда я получаю значения.

Всё вроде бы работает, но значения не обновляются. Остаётся первоначальное значение, которое мы получили при открытии / обновлении страницы.

Comment: а что именно не работает ? какие значения не обновляются ? элемент $("#document1") не меняется что-ли ?

Comment: Да. Допустим в первом документе значение из бд. (На самом деле немного не то, но не суть) Элемент $("#document1") выдаёт только то, что имел первый документ при открытии второго. Не обновляется вообщем.

Comment: ошибка в консоли есть ? http запрос происходит ?

Comment: Да, происходит.

Comment: > получает определённые значения

@Maykop, Откуда и куда вы передаете эти значения? И как вы их передаете? Т.к. тут не в JS дело скорее всего. Сделайте простой тест - в первом документе оставьте всё как есть, а во втором (*document.php*, который подгружаете) только строку: echo date('H:i:s'); Будет выводиться время разное или одно и то же.

Comment: @Maykop, ну что вы как Штирлиц на допросе.. это вам же интересно чтобы работало, а не нам.

Comment: Да знаю..
Вообщем, время передвигается после обновления страницы. А если допустим щёлкнуть на ссылку, и перейти на другую страницу, а потом так же ссылкой вернутся на прошлую - время замирает.

Comment: @Maykop, какое время ? откуда оно здесь. причем тут load....

Comment: Добавил в подгружаемый документ для теста строчку: "echo date('H:i:s');", как предложил Deonis.